# Possible to highlight path in many-nested css menu?

Tags: javascript, php, css, menu, navigation

I've created a four-layer menu using CSS (ul and li) combined with PHP which pulls the options out of a database. It's not for navigation but to allow the user to filter up to a certain level of detail

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7LFT5/

If you take the path "part of building" > "exterior" > "garage / car port" > "garage door", you'll see that the user would easily get confused about what path they've taken.

I'd like to highlight the path they took in a different colour. It would be ideal to do this in CSS - which feels like it should be possible, since the path is generating the visibility of menu items. I've been playing around with the css below, hoping :hover or :active would work - but no luck yet.

```
nav.filter li ul li ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 170px;
    top: 0px;
    /* margin: 0px; */
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: That should work perfectly. Why don't you try it out, and then report back if you have any problems?

Comment: the highlist has to be in different colours or is one colour just fine? --- then check @Danko ´s answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I hadn't seen that use of CSS before. You've saved me hours - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this selector:

> nav.filter ul li a:hover {

Because you need to keep the highlight on the `a` tag when hover the entire content of the `li`

To this:

> nav.filter ul li:hover > a {

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/7LFT5/1/

Now combining the two selectors you can have one color for the active and one on the hover item like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/7LFT5/3/